# Hover on title of Highcharter graph.

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I'm trying to add like an information box on hover on title of the highcharter graph. When the user hovers over title, it should show some information about the graph. Can this be achieved using Highcharter in R ?

Thank You! Here is a sample code to which I want to add hover property for title.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

n <- 5

set.seed(123)

colors <- c("#d35400", "#2980b9", "#2ecc71", "#f1c40f", "#2c3e50", "#7f8c8d")
colors2 <- c("#000004", "#3B0F70", "#8C2981", "#DE4968", "#FE9F6D", "#FCFDBF")


df <- data.frame(x = seq_len(n) - 1) %>% 
  mutate(
    y = 10 + x + 10 * sin(x),
    y = round(y, 1),
    z = (x*y) - median(x*y),
    e = 10 * abs(rnorm(length(x))) + 2,
    e = round(e, 1),
    low = y - e,
    high = y + e,
    value = y,
    name = sample(fruit[str_length(fruit) <= 5], size = n),
    color = rep(colors, length.out = n),
    segmentColor = rep(colors2, length.out = n)
  )

create_hc <- function(t) {

  dont_rm_high_and_low <- c("arearange", "areasplinerange",
                            "columnrange", "errorbar")

  is_polar <- str_detect(t, "polar")

  t <- str_replace(t, "polar", "")

  if(!t %in% dont_rm_high_and_low) df <- df %>% select(-e, -low, -high)


  highchart() %>%
    hc_title(text = paste(ifelse(is_polar, "polar ", ""), t, '\u2370'),
             style = list(fontSize = "15px")) %>% 
    hc_chart(type = t,
             polar = is_polar) %>% 
    hc_xAxis(categories = df$name) %>% 
    hc_add_series(df, name = "Fruit Consumption", showInLegend = FALSE) 

}

hcs <- c("line")  %>% 
  map(create_hc)
```

Comment: Hi Siddharth Jain, here is an example how it can be done in JS: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lvfsd2c5/

Comment: From a user experience perspective, why would you not want to show this information to the user by default, either as a source line or subtitle? I would be concerned that users would not know to hover over the title to learn more about your chart.

Comment: Hi Mike, so title and subtitle show the main information. I also have some definitions related to graph to show. Hence I wanted it to be shown when hovered as it is important but extra information. Any thoughts on how you would approach this ?

Comment: @SiddharthJain In my experience, additional notes, definitions, and data sources are shown below the chart. Depending on how long this information is, you could include that data as a “credits” text or add it using the “renderer” function after the chart has been drawn. The benefit there is that if the user exports the chart, that text appears in the exported file. I can point you to an example, if you like.

Comment: @MikeZavarello yes I'd like that very much! Please do.

Comment: @SiddharthJain Here's an example that shows how I use the renderer function to add source line text: https://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/wmty0tqe/. Look at line 192 in the JavaScript. See also this page from the Highcharts documentation: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer. Adding text using the renderer function is all the way at the bottom.